# Calculate balance from a sorted list of transactions in Python

Tags: python, transactions, calculation

I'm a designer working for a bank and I'm trying to create a python script that will create a CSV of random transactions (using random and datetime to create). It'll save a lot of time and brain power in my prototypes.

I can generate a list of multiple transactions, each containing a date and amount, however, I'm struggling to calculate the balance. Specifically, it's because I need to sort the list by date, then do the balance calculation and I can't figure out how to do this after the date sort has taken place. (In previous attempts I've found the new balance calculation doesn't update the global variable, only the individual transaction line balance.)

I've been getting lost in with or without classes/dictionary approach and wanted to get some outside opinions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


ledger = [] #complete ledger (multiple transactions)
today = datetime.now()
account_balance = 1500

def create_date():  

    ''' Create date for transaction'''
    date_step = random.randrange(1, 11) # Set range of days
    raw_date = today + timedelta(days=-date_step)

    ''' Format date to match app's format'''
    date = raw_date.strftime('%w %b %y')

    return date

def create_amount():
    
    ''' Create amount up to 10.00 '''
    raw_number = round(random.uniform(0.10, 10.0), 2)

    return raw_number

def create_ledger(x):
    global ledger
        
    for n in range(x):
        transaction = create_date(), create_amount() 
        ledger.append(transaction)
    
    date_sort = lambda item: item[0]
    ledger.sort(key=date_sort, reverse=True)

    print(ledger)

create_ledger(10)
```

Comment: Your ledger currently looks something like this `[('6 Aug 20', 3.5), ('6 Aug 20', 4.03), ('5 Aug 20', 1.98),('4 Aug 20', 4.52)]` are you simply trying to sum the second element of each tuple?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for having a look. I'm trying to take the second element away from the global account_balance, and then return an updated account_balance value. So the tuple would be (date, amount, balance)

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort it by descending order in date:

```
def create_ledger(x):
    global ledger
        
    for n in range(x):
        transaction = create_date(), create_amount() 
        ledger.append(transaction)
    
    date_sort = lambda item: item[0]
    ledger.sort(key=date_sort, reverse=False) #<- set reverse=False

    print(ledger)
```

Run a for loop across your ledger and replace it this way

```
for i in range(len(ledger)):
    tup = ledger[i]
    account_balance -= tup[1]
    ledger[i] = (tup[0],tup[1],account_balance)
```

If you really want the date sorted by ascending, re-sort it after it has generated this output.

Example output:

```
[('1 Aug 20', 1.72, 1498.28),
 ('2 Aug 20', 1.54, 1496.74),
 ('2 Aug 20', 3.47, 1493.27),
 ('2 Aug 20', 4.46, 1488.81),
 ('2 Aug 20', 4.53, 1484.28),
 ('3 Aug 20', 5.46, 1478.82),
 ('3 Aug 20', 5.93, 1472.8899999999999),
 ('4 Aug 20', 0.96, 1471.9299999999998),
 ('5 Aug 20', 4.72, 1467.2099999999998),
 ('6 Aug 20', 2.51, 1464.6999999999998)]
```

Word of warning, your entire process is good for generating relatively small toy example `csv`'s only, since it'll scale horribly.

Furthermore, whenever you're dealing with finance related software, you should honestly be using `int`'s instead of `float`'s since floats have [serious rounding errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) that can build up (see how the last few rows of account_balance has some absurdly long numbers).

IIRC the standard practice is to multiply everything by 100 and store them as `int`'s, so you will be dealing with cents instead of dollars of whatever currency you're using.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's really helpful 